# pict2e: Cannot use decimal line slope argument inserted from macro

Tags: errors, math-operators, floating-point, picture-mode

I am implementing nonstandard operators by drawing them as pictures using the `pict2e` package and then scaling them to fit in the various math modes. I store the picture's parameters in external macros and invoke them in the `picture` body.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\def\num{3}
\def\decimal{3.2}
\newcommand*\testfigure{%
    \begin{picture}(3,3)(0,0)
        \put(0, 0){\line(0, \decimal){\num}}
    \end{picture}
}

\begin{document}
    \testfigure
\end{document}
```

Compiling this on Overleaf and my local TeX Live installation, however, raises an error: *Missing = inserted for `\ifnum`*. This is followed by another error: *Missing number, treated as 0*. Note that this behavior repeats when I define the `\decimal` macro with `\newcommand`. It also happens when the number has a decimal point but no fractional part (e.g. 3. and 3.0).

This behavior recurs with `\vector`, but not with `\qbezier` or any of the other picture commands.

If I replace the `\decimal` invocation with a literal decimal number, compilation succeeds. I know `pict2e` supports real slope arguments, as opposed to the coprimality restriction of `picture`. I also know that `\ifnum` acts on integers only.

Why does compilation fail in this case, and why only with `\line`? How can I properly give `\line` a decimal slope argument from a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in `pict2e`. I mailed the maintainers and Rolf replied positively. He incorporated the changes below and the problem should be fixed now (version 0.3c, 20-08-2019).

---

The macro `\pIIe@checkslopeargs` used to do:

```latex
\renewcommand*\pIIe@checkslopeargs[3]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}\expandafter\pIIe@checkslopearg\@tempa.:{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}\expandafter\pIIe@checkslopearg\@tempa.:{#3}%
  \ifdim #1\p@=\z@ \ifdim #2\p@=\z@ \@badlinearg \fi\fi}
```

It stores the first argument in a temporary macro (`\def\@tempa{#1}`), then expands that temporary macro and calls `\pIIe@checkslopearg` with that. However the line

```latex
\def\@tempa{#1}\expandafter\pIIe@checkslopearg\@tempa.:{#3}
```

does exactly the same as the simpler

```latex
\pIIe@checkslopearg#1.:{#3}
```

and when `\pIIe@checkslopearg` expands, splitting `#1` in the `.`, it doesn't find the dot if it is hidden in your `\decimal` macro, but it does work if you pass it explicitly. After that a decimal number goes into an `\ifnum` test, essentially becoming `\ifnum3.2<\z@`, which fails with `Missing = inserted for \ifnum`.

The fact that the argument is stored in a temporary macro and the code *does* support decimal numbers, leads me to believe this is a bug. To fix it you can replace the two `\def` by `\edef`. I also added a missing space in a macro which would trigger unnecessary expansion.

Put this in your preamble, after loading `pict2e`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\pIIe@checkslopeargs[3]{%
%  V \edef instead of \def
  \edef\@tempa{#1}\expandafter\pIIe@checkslopearg\@tempa.:{#3}%
  \edef\@tempa{#2}\expandafter\pIIe@checkslopearg\@tempa.:{#3}%
  \ifdim #1\p@=\z@ \ifdim #2\p@=\z@ \@badlinearg \fi\fi}
\def\pIIe@checkslopearg #1.#2:#3{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\empty\def\@tempa{0}\fi
  \ifx\@tempa\space\def\@tempa{0}\fi%  V added space
  \ifnum\ifnum\@tempa<\z@-\fi\@tempa>#3 \@badlinearg \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. Your solution works well.